# Вывод значения localStorage

Tags: javascript, jquery, localstorage

Устанавливаю значение localStorage

```
localStorage[tovarid] = value;
```

Как я могу его вывести в `div` на своей странице без перезагрузки страницы,сразу же,просто если получать значение и выводить,нужно перезагружать страницу.

Comment: Если вы заносите значение в хранилище, то вы на тот же момент имеете переменную со значением, которую заносите...... так берите значение из этой же переменной и пуляйте в див

Comment: Так я делал,но интересно,можно ли сразу

Comment: @zkolya, что сделал, и почему считаешь, что это не сразу

Comment: @zkolya работает оно сразу в любом случае... это же не кукисы.... как пример:  `localStorage.setItem('test', 'myTestValue'); console.log(localStorage.getItem('test'))` - выведет сразу значение ключа `test`, которое внес перед выводом..... может у вас до перезагрузки и значения то нет, которые вы в хранилище пытаетесь внести?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`localStorage` работает вне зависимости от перезагрузки страницы. Единственное что помешает получить запомненное в `localStorage` значение это закрытие браузера. PS Не путать `localStorage` с `sessionStorage`.

Comment: я накосячил, выводил значения при загрузке документа,а в момент добавления ничего не делал.